Deformation invariance of cohomology and Chern classes
Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a smooth projective morphism between smooth complex quasi-projective varieties. Then it is known that each fiber of $f$ has isomorphic cohomology ring. I'm wondering if the following cohomology class is also deformation invariant:
(1) If $L$ is a line bundle on $X$, then is the first Chern class $c_1(L_y)\in H^{2i}(X_y, \mathbb{Q})$ vanishing for a point $y\in Y$ implies it is vanishing for all $y\in Y$?
(2) If $Z\subset X$ is a smooth subvariety such that $Z\to Y$ is also smooth, for any two points $y,y'\in Y$, can we always choose an isomorphism $H^*(X_y, \mathbb{Q})\cong H^*(X_{y'}, \mathbb{Q})$ which maps $ch(\mathcal{O}_{Z_y})$ to $ch(\mathcal{O}_{Z_{y'}})$?

Since you're over complex numbers, in the analytic topology the maps $X \to Y$ and $Z \to Y$ are proper submersions and therefore fiber bundles by Ehresmann's theorem (and $Z \hookrightarrow X$ is an inclusion of fiber bundles). Now both questions have a positive answer by noting that the inclusion of fibers $X_y \hookrightarrow X$ and $(X_y, Z_y) \hookrightarrow (X, Z)$ are homotopic for varying $y$ (when $Y$ connected).
